# Adding Cover Art to downloaded mp3 on Android

Tags: android, mp3, id3, download-manager, id3-tag

How do I add a cover art (album art) to a downloaded mp3 programmatically?

I am letting my app download a mp3 file via the DownloadManager from the Android APIS as shown below:

```
private void startDownload(){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL+DOWNLOAD+mp3+".mp3");

    filename = title+".mp3";

    Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(MUSIC_PATH, filename);

    DOWNLOAD_MANAGER.enqueue(request);
}
```

Is it possible to add a coverart to the downloaded mp3 file, so that the mp3 player on the phone will show a image while playing the song?

Comment: Is the cover art embedded in these MP3 files? If so, then I think that the music / media player app will be able to sort that out for you on its own. If the cover is not embedded you will have to: 1) obtain a cover image file from somewhere, 2) [embed it into your MP3 file](http://www.richardfarrar.com/embedding-album-art-in-mp3-files/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download this jar file [MyID3_for_android](https://sites.google.com/site/eternalsandbox/myid3-for-android) and add it to your project's build path. here is a sample code of how you can change the cover

```
        File src = new File("filepath");
        MusicMetadataSet src_set = new MyID3().read(src);

        File img = (new File("imagePath"));


        Vector<ImageData> fileList = new Vector<ImageData>();
        ImageData data = new ImageData(readFile(img), "", "", 3);
        fileList.add(data);

        MusicMetadata metadata =  (MusicMetadata) src_set.getSimplified();
        metadata.setPictureList(fileList);

        File dst = new File("destinationPath");

        new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);
```

You Will need also the [Jakarta Regex jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/regexp/jakarta-regexp-1.5.zip)

readFile is only a function to get byte[] from File

```
public static byte[] readFile (File file) throws IOException {
    // Open file
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

    try {
        // Get and check length
        long longlength = f.length();
        int length = (int) longlength;
        if (length != longlength) throw new IOException("File size >= 2 GB");

        // Read file and return data
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        f.readFully(data);
        return data;
    }
    finally {
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Got it from stackOverflow , dont know from who :)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I couldn't find an answer to this. I'd give you several upvotes if I could.

Comment: Did the same but unable to play the audio file.Any idea why?